# Surnames swapped in my US visa. Can I still use that visa to travel?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I have my visa with my surnames swapped — instead of being *Garcia Lopez* it is written in my Visa as *Lopez Garcia*, the surname is written correctly just swapped I was wondering if that would be a problem in the US?

Comment: If I were you, I'd ask the issuing consulate to correct their error.

Comment: Yes, this would be a problem unless your passport has also them swapped.

Comment: While you should try to get the consulate to correct the error, it's also true that everyone has seen this error with Spanish-style names before.

Comment: US immigration won't be your only problem, but also getting on the plane. Get it fixed ***immediately*** with the consulate

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's a problem.

No matter where you are traveling Globally, your name Must be identical on All documentation: Passport, Airplane Tickets, Visas, everything.